# how to get joomla menu object based on name?

Tags: php, joomla

This question is bit specific to joomla.

I know if with the code `$menu = &JSite::getMenu()` I can get the reference object of the complete menu. But how can i get a specif menu based on the name?

My Scenario :
I have footer-menu with items : home | about us | rules | privacy policy.

I need to display links to two menu items Rules and privacy policy in a component. I cannot hard code the links, as the itemid would be different in development and production environment.

Do we have some workaround like `$menu = &JSite::getMenu()->get('footer-menu')->getMenuItem('rules');` which can give me refrence object to a particular menu item, from which I can create my links for that particular article.

Thanks,
Tanmay

Comment: Seems its friday fever!!! :( no one seems to be online... Please help me.. atleast on Monday :)

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there isn't a built-in way to do this. But I feel your pain.

Here's an adaptation of a function I built before. It's not recursive, so you'll only get one level deep in a menu hierarchy, but that was enough for me.

```
function getMenuItems( $parentAlias ) {
    $db =& JFactory::getDBO();
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM #__menu WHERE parent in ' .
           '(SELECT id FROM #__menu WHERE alias='.$db->Quote($parentAlias).') '.
           'AND published=1 ORDER BY ordering';
    $db->setQuery($sql);
    $results = $db->loadObjectList();
}
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Garrett Bluma, Well at the end I did something bit similar to your implementation, created a function in the model, to get me object for the menu items I want. Thanks for your reply. At least it confirmed that i am not missing a great function of joomla :)

Answer (score 2):

**Method #1:**

```
$menu = & JSite::getMenu();
$item = $menu->getItems('link', 'index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=1', true);
```

**Method #2:**

```
$menu = & JSite::getMenu();
$item = $menu->getItems('alias', 'rules', true);
```